# Does pagespeed have issues with flex-wrap? If so, what's the solution?

Tags: css, flexbox, pagespeed

My site looks absolutely fine in all significant browsers on windows, on my Nexus 6 and in chrome devtools simulating a range of mobile devices.

But when I put it through google pagespeed it appears my flex-wrap:wrap rule is being ignored, and I get a terrible score as such.

I don't mind that in itself, it's just a "score", but for all I know google is using the same rendering engine to affect search ranking results.

I'm **pretty** certain I'm not doing anything stupid...

Comment: Would you mind sharing the report here? It would be helpful to know which rules you are getting a low score before answering your question.

Comment: It's "The page content is too wide for the viewport, forcing the user to scroll horizontally.".  And the screenshot in the fake phone clearly shows the problem, that two boxes are sitting side by side, when in fact one should have wrapped under the other.  (And it does do that on all my other testing, just not on pagespeed!

Comment: hmm I'd have to see some code to give a more in depth answer